# Conexao Sql Server Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Estou com problema na configuração de conexão com banco de dados Sql Server tenho esse método de conexão mas me dar essa mensagem de erro quando rodo o aplicativo

```
public static ISessionFactory CriaConexao()
    {
        try
        {
            if (SessionFactory == null)

                lock (typeof(NHibernateHelper))
                {
                    FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                   .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnectionString")
                       .ShowSql())
                   .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())).
                   configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                }

            return SessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.write(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

// {“Valor não pode ser nulo.\r\nNome do parâmetro: Data Source”
```

AppConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=CARLOS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PAF-ECF;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> E:\PROJETO C#\AutomacaoComercial\FrenteCaixa\App.config

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" /></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Já passei por isso também

Tente utilizar a seguinte Connection tring:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Qualquer dúvida pesquise neste link tb: [Value cannot be null, Parameter name: Data Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/3-PO-I1y3u4)

Abraço

Comment: Henrique deu certo também não amigo

Comment: então faz o seguinte:

troca isso:

.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnectionString")

por isso:

.ConnectionString(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString)

Comment: nessa string de conexão não está sendo indicado qual banco será usado.

Comment: ola o resultado (Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString) mensagem de erro   {"An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: Barbetta a string está indicando sim o banco a ser usado